# Exact solution to a system of Ito SDE's in order to study convergence behaviour

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I'm working on a simple stock pricing model described by the following model of Ito SDE's:
$$
d S_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma_t S_t dB^1_t \\
d \sigma_t = -(\sigma_t - \xi_t)dt + p \sigma_t dB^2 _t \\
d \xi_t = \frac{1}{\alpha}(\sigma_t - \xi_t) dt
$$
With $\mu=0.10$, $S_0 = $ €50, $\sigma_0 = 0.20$, $\xi_0 = 0.20$, $\alpha = 1$, and $p=1$.

So I implemented Euler and Milstein schemes for this model, but now I want to study the convergence behaviour of both schemes. In order to do that, I need to know the error to the exact solution, so I would need the exact solution of the model.
Using Ito's lemma with $\phi = \ln(S_t)$ gives the following solution for $S_t$, since $\sigma_t$ is independent from $S_t$:
$$
S(t) = S_0 e^{(\mu  -\sigma_t^2/2)t + \sigma_t B^1(t)}
$$

However, I'm really stuck trying to get the exact solution of $\sigma_t$ and $\xi_t$. Could someone please help me out? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With time-dependent $\sigma_t$ the solution for $S_t$ is rather
$$
S_t=S_0\exp\Big(\mu t-\int_0^t\sigma^2_s/2+\int_0^t\sigma_s\,B^1_s\Big)\,.
$$
Even if you manage to solve for $\sigma_t$ explicitly that solution for $S_t$ remains un-integrated explicitly. You should come up with a simpler example to test your schemes.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did already test my schemes for $\sigma_t = \sigma_0$ and got the correct order of convergence (1 for Milstein strong convergence, 0.5 for Euler strong convergence).